# Simulate the sum of $n$ dependent bernoulli random variables.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, simulation

Simulate the sum of $n$ dependent bernoulli random variables.

I know that the sum of $n$ independent bernoulli radom variables with probability $p$ is distributed as a binomial random variable. I found that there are multiple models that can be usefull to approximate the sum when the bernoulli random variables are dependent with correlation $q$. In this case I'm useing this one: $$f_X(x) = \binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}e^{-x(n-x)q}$$$

I´m trying to simulate it in R but I don´t know how to mix this two in a random sample. Any suggestions would be great!

Here is my code so far:

```
sumaBerdep <- function (n,p,q)
{
  x <- rbern(n,p)
  y <- sample(n, replace = T)
  return(sum(x)*exp(-y*(n-y)*q))
}
binom <- replicate(n, sumaBerdep(10, 0.5, 0.3))
p <- table(binom)/10^5
plot(p, type = 'h')
```

[image]

Comment: What is $y$ supposed to be?

Comment: What does "Bernoulli random variables are dependent with probability $q$" mean?  Is there a probability $q$ that they are all the same? Or something else?

Comment: I just made some edits. Thanks for the observations!